# The way to check a HDFS directory's size?

Tags: hadoop, command-line, directory, hdfs

I know `du -sh` in common Linux filesystems. But how to do that with HDFS?

Answer (score 200, accepted):

Prior to 0.20.203, and officially deprecated in 2.6.0:

```
hadoop fs -dus [directory]
```

Since <strike>[0.20.203](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.203.0/file_system_shell.html#du)</strike> (dead link) [1.0.4](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/file_system_shell.html#du) and still compatible through [2.6.0](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#du):

```
hdfs dfs -du [-s] [-h] URI [URI …]
```

You can also run `hadoop fs -help` for more info and specifics.

Comment: -du -s (-dus is deprecated)

Answer (score 90):

`hadoop fs -du -s -h /path/to/dir` displays a directory's size in readable form.

Comment: For newer versions of hdfs, `hdfs -du -s -h /path/to/dir` it's more appropriate.

Answer (score 47):

Extending to [Matt D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/698839/matt-d) and others answers, the command can be till ***Apache Hadoop 3.0.0***

> ## `hadoop fs -du [-s] [-h] [-v] [-x] URI [URI ...]`

> It displays sizes of files and directories contained in the given directory or the length of a file in case it's just a file.

> ### Options:

> - The **-s** option will result in an **aggregate summary of file lengths** being displayed, rather than the individual files. Without the -s option, the calculation is done by going 1-level deep from the given path.
> - The **-h** option will format file sizes in a **human-readable** fashion (e.g 64.0m instead of 67108864)
> - The **-v** option will display **the names of columns** as a header line.
> - The **-x** option will **exclude snapshots** from the result calculation. Without the -x option (default), the result is always calculated from all INodes, including all snapshots under the given path.

#### `du` returns three columns with the following format:

```
 +-------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
 | size  |  disk_space_consumed_with_all_replicas  |  full_path_name | 
 +-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

### Example command:

```
hadoop fs -du /user/hadoop/dir1 \
    /user/hadoop/file1 \
    hdfs://nn.example.com/user/hadoop/dir1
```

Exit Code: Returns 0 on success and -1 on error.

[source: Apache doc](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#du)

Comment: +1 for the information about the results! I didn't understand why I was getting two results (size and disk_space) instead of one. Thanks!

Comment: `disk_space = size * replication_factor `

Answer (score 13):

With this you will get size in GB

```
hdfs dfs -du PATHTODIRECTORY | awk '/^[0-9]+/ { print int($1/(1024**3)) " [GB]\t" $2 }'
```

Comment: hdfs dfs -du PATHTODIRECTORY | awk '/^[0-9]+/ { print int($1/(1024**3) " [GB]\t" $2 }' - Please update your command. Two closing bracket after 1024**3. It should be only 1

Answer (score 5):

When trying to calculate the total of a particular group of files within a directory the `-s` option does not work (in Hadoop 2.7.1). For example:

Directory structure:

```
some_dir
├abc.txt    
├count1.txt 
├count2.txt 
└def.txt
```

Assume each file is 1 KB in size. You can summarize the entire directory with:

```
hdfs dfs -du -s some_dir
4096 some_dir
```

However, if I want the sum of all files containing "count" the command falls short.

```
hdfs dfs -du -s some_dir/count*
1024 some_dir/count1.txt
1024 some_dir/count2.txt
```

To get around this I usually pass the output through awk.

```
hdfs dfs -du some_dir/count* | awk '{ total+=$1 } END { print total }'
2048
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to get the folder size in a human readable format is

```
hdfs dfs -du -h /folderpath
```

where `-s` can be added to get the total sum

Answer (score 2):

To get the size of the directory **hdfs dfs -du -s -h /$yourDirectoryName** can be used. 
hdfs dfsadmin -report can be used to see a quick cluster level storage report.

Comment: The -s did the trick, otherwise, it gave me a full list of files which I then have to tally up.

Answer (score 1):

hadoop version 2.3.33:

```
hadoop fs -dus  /path/to/dir  |   awk '{print $2/1024**3 " G"}'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

% of used space on Hadoop cluster
`sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs –df`

Capacity under specific folder:
`sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -du -h /user`

Comment: I got an error with "hdfs", the way it worked for me was: `hadoop fs -du -h /user`  (i didn't need to use `sudo`)

Comment: `sudo` is not needed and should be used sparingly.

Answer (score 0):

`hdfs dfs -count <dir>`

info from man page:

```
-count [-q] [-h] [-v] [-t [<storage type>]] [-u] <path> ... :
  Count the number of directories, files and bytes under the paths
  that match the specified file pattern.  The output columns are:
  DIR_COUNT FILE_COUNT CONTENT_SIZE PATHNAME
  or, with the -q option:
  QUOTA REM_QUOTA SPACE_QUOTA REM_SPACE_QUOTA
        DIR_COUNT FILE_COUNT CONTENT_SIZE PATHNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

**Incase if someone is need through pythonic way :)**

- Install `hdfs` python package

  `pip install hdfs`
- code

  ```
  from hdfs import InsecureClient

  client = InsecureClient('http://hdfs_ip_or_nameservice:50070',user='hdfs')
  folder_info = client.content("/tmp/my/hdfs/path")

  #prints folder/directory size in bytes
  print(folder_info['length'])
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Command Should be `hadoop fs -du -s -h \dirPath`

- **-du** [-s] [-h]  ... :   Show the amount of space, in bytes, used by the files that match the specified   file pattern.
- **-s** : Rather than showing the size of each individual file that matches the
          pattern, shows the total (summary) size.
- **-h** : Formats the sizes of files in a human-readable fashion rather than a number of bytes. (Ex MB/GB/TB etc)

  Note that, even without the -s option, this only shows size summaries one level
  deep into a directory.

  The output is in the form 
      size    name(full path)

Comment: duplicate answer