# Size of HDFS filesystem using du command

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I know "du -h" command gives the disk usage in human readable format. But please let me know what are the two values showing up while using the "du -h" command on HDFS filesystem for my Hadoop Cluster.

```
  [hduser@node2 ~]$ sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -du -h /
                    6.3 K    768.0 M  /hbase
                    0        0        /tmp
                    371.6 M  743.2 M  /user
```

Output for directories inside Hbase:

```
    [hduser@node1 ~]$ sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -du -h /hbase/WALs
0    0      /hbase/WALs/hregion-90735520
0    0      /hbase/WALs/node1.example.com,60020,1463323242824
166  512 M  /hbase/WALs/node1.example.com,60020,1464088636041
0    0      /hbase/WALs/node2.example.com,60020,1463321374329
0    0      /hbase/WALs/node2.example.com,60020,1463998874513
0    0      /hbase/WALs/node2.example.com,60020,1464024047168
83   256 M  /hbase/WALs/node2.example.com,60020,1464100746376
[hduser@node1 ~]$
```

Answer (score 3):

For given command

```
[hduser@node2 ~]$ sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -du -h /
```

#### The du returned three columns and those are:

```
+----------+--------------------------------------+----------------+
|  size    |disk_space_consumed_with_all_replicas | full_path_name |
+----------+--------------------------------------+----------------+
|  6.3 K   |   768.0 M                            |    /hbase      |
|  0       |   0                                  |    /tmp        |
|  371.6 M |   743.2 M                            |    /user       |
+----------+--------------------------------------+----------------+
```

[SO Answer for detailed usage of `du`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46161352/1592191)